# How do I move parts of my sql results to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a basic query that retrieves the following output:

```
select * from clients where ID in ('7320039', '851236')
```

Results:

```
ID      date_of_birth   desc        create_timestamp
7320039 20130319        MMR         3/21/2014
7320039 20130319        MMR         6/23/2014
851236  20140102        HIB         4/5/2014
851236  20140102        HIB         6/8/2014
```

However, I would like my results output to look like this:

Results:

```
ID      date_of_birth   desc        create_timestamp    New_col
7320039 20130319        MMR         3/21/2014           6/23/2014 
851236  20140102        HIB         4/5/2014            6/8/2014
```

Comment: What is new_col ? And why isn't it in the SELECT list ?  Do not use `SELECT *` - use the exact column list like `SELECT First_col, Second_col, Third_col, Etc_col`   The problem with `*` is that you easily make mistakes

Comment: By looking at your data you want `new_col` value as `max(create_timestamp)` if that's right then you can use the `Group by` with `min` and `max`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `min`and `max` functions to get that output:

```
select 
    ID, date_of_birth, [desc], 
    MIN(create_timestamp) create_timestamp, 
    MAX(create_timestamp) new_col 
from clients where ID in ('7320039', '851236')
group by ID, date_of_birth, [desc]
```

Since you didn't explain the logic behind the transformation this may, or may not, be what you are looking for.

Comment: what is that `[desc]` notation ? for descending ?

Comment: @Coffee No, `desc` is one of the columns in the sample data, but as it is a reserved keyword it needs to be enclosed in brackets. The reserved word is of course `desc` for descending.